# Collection.filter: Can't apply calendarRange filter to objects without a timestamp

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to compute the minimum and maximum of monthly precipitation data. However, I get the following error:

```
Collection.filter: Can't apply calendarRange filter to objects without a timestamp.
```

This is my code:

```
// Map over the years and create a monthly collection for the sowing season
exports.monthly_Sowing_Precip = function (sowCol){
 return ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
   years.map(function(year) {
     return sowingMonths.map(function(month) {
       return sowCol.set('system:time_start',sowCol.get('system:time_start'))
       .set({'month': month, 'year': year})
       .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(year, year, 'year'))
       .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(month, month, 'month'))
       .sum();
 });
}).flatten())}

// compute Minimum for each month across all years ---------------------------------------
// i.e. Minimum for all months in the sowing collection
exports.monthly_Sowing_Min = function (sowCol){
 return ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
   sowingMonths.map(function(month) {
     return sowCol
     .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(month, month, 'month'))
     .min()
     .set('month', month);
 }))};

// compute monthly averages ---------------------------------------------------------
var monthly_Sowing_Precip  =  monthlyComposites.monthly_Sowing_Precip(sowCol)   
// compute monthly min --------------------------------------------------------------
var monthly_Sowing_Min  = monthlyComposites.monthly_Sowing_Min(monthly_Sowing_Precip)
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing `.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(month, month, 'month')`  to  `.filter(ee.Filter.eq('month', month))` in the `.monthly_Sowing_Min` function.